# Using Lombok @Data annotation above class with field names like "iPhone" causing problems

Tags: java, lombok

I'am using Lombok 1.18.18. and Intellij Idea 2020.3.1. `@Data` annotation above class with field name like "iPhone" (starts with a single lowercase letter followed by a capital) causing `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` when calling field setter like `object.setIPhone("")` or getter like `object.getIPhone()`. There is no error during compilation time that could indicates that generated method names which I used are wrong.

Is it happening only to me or is it some kind of known problem with field names like this?

Comment: Do you have the lombok plugin in your intelliJ?

Comment: Yes. It's built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a simple replication, and it works as expected.

Snippet code:

```
@Data
public class Hola {

    int mundo;
    int iPhone;
}



public class Mundo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hola hola = new Hola();
        hola.setIPhone(13);

        System.out.println(hola.getIPhone());
    }

}
```

Did you try to compile and run outside of Intellij?

It seems to be more related to your IDE. Maybe annotation processing is disabled.

Comment: Seems really like problem of my IDE. Invalidating caches with resart helped.